Cornering the stalk market achievement
The "Cornering the Stalk Market" achievement is fairly vague:

Let's just say you've harvested your share of the profits.

You have a total for this achievement; how is it affected:

If you don't sell your turnips and they rot.
If you sell your turnips on another island
If you turn your turnips into a crafted object (e.g barrels) and sell those?


I have done some testing over the weekend to determine what affects the achievement and can report:
The only way the achievement "level" changes is if you sell turnips on your own island.
So;

If you don't sell your turnips and they rot: The achievement level is not affected.
If you sell your turnips on another island: You make money as normal, but the achievement level is not affected.
If you turn your turnips into a crafted object (Eg barrels) and sell those? The achievement level is not affected, but you make money from the crafted barrels. (Good luck, this takes forever!)

